# Ruby on Rails : Errno::EACCES (Permission denied - oo_26502

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linux, ruby-on-rails-3, file-permissions

I have a Rails app running under Apache/passenger, the user uploads a file, the file is written to /tmp, then the app tries to read the same file, and returns the above error.

/tmp has these permissions

drwxrwxrwt   7 root root   4096 Feb 28 16:25 tmp

and the file written in /tmp is owned by "app"

-rw-r--r--  1 app       www  74359 Feb 28 15:07 filename.xlsx

Why am I getting this error?

Answer (score 0):

Needed ROO_TMP to be defined, see

http://nopressure.co.uk/post/25029398591/errno-eacces-in-controller-upload-rails-roo